# 'El índice -1 no tiene un valor.' datagridview

Tags: c#, windows-forms, datagridview

Buen día a todos.
Estoy teniendo un error bastante extraño que no comprendo con un `DataGridView` de windows forms con c#
Tengo un datagrid que lo estoy llenando con una lista de objetos. La lista de objetos es la siguiente:

```
public class DgvDetalleNota
    {
        public int IdArticulo { get; set; }
        public string Articulo { get; set; }
        public decimal PrecioVenta { get; set; }
        public int Cantidad { get; set; }
        public decimal Total { get; set; }
    }
```

Creo una lista en el form, que es donde iré agregando mis registros. Esa misma lista es la que utilizo para mostrar datos en mi datagrid:

```
private readonly List<DgvDetalleNota> DetallesNotas;
        public FrmPuntoVenta()
        {
            DetallesNotas = new List<DgvDetalleNota>();
            InitializeComponent();
            SetDgv();
        }
        private void SetDgv()
        {
            dgvVentas.DataSource = null;
            dgvVentas.DataSource = DetallesNotas;
        }
```

Tengo otros métodos que agregan y eliminan elementos de la lista, pero no considero que sean necesarios. Todos se resumen en modificar los elementos de la lista, y usar ese método `SetDgv()` para actualizar el datagrid.
También tengo un `CellDoubleClic` de ese datagrid:

```
private void DgvVentas_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            var row = dgvVentas.Rows[e.RowIndex];
            txtIdArticulo.Text = row.Cells["IdArticulo"].Value.ToString();
            txtPrecioUnitario.Text= row.Cells["PrecioUnitario"].Value.ToString();
            txtDescripcionArticulo.Text= row.Cells["Descripcion"].Value.ToString();
            txtCantidad.Text= row.Cells["Cantidad"].Value.ToString();
            ExistenciaArticulo = articulosCat.BuscarPorId(Convert.ToInt32(txtIdArticulo.Text)).Existencia - Convert.ToInt32(txtCantidad.Text);
        }
```

El problema que tengo radica en que si hago clic en el datagrid, me marca el siguiente error:

```
'El índice -1 no tiene un valor.'
```

Para ser específico, en `StackTrace` marca que el error es en el siguiente elemento:

```
at System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.get_Item(Int32 index)
at System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.get_Current()
```

Lo que no entiendo, es que ese error me lo está mostrando en el `program.cs`, es decir, **en el archivo de inicio del proyecto**, no en el datagrid del form en el que tengo el error.

Intenté eliminar ese datagrid y poner otro con ese mismo nombre, pensando que era algún error por algo que haya movido cuando configuraba el form, pero el error persiste.

Lo único que se me ocurre es que tenga que ver con el que use la lista en la que añado elementos, que por ser la misma que uso para pintar el datagrid, pero la verdad no sabría del porqué.

Así mismo, ví que hay una pregunta similar en el sitio pero la respuesta no me ayudó.
¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: El error te da cuando das click en alguna celda o fuera de ella?

Comment: @Nathy al hacer clic en alguna celda, pero aclaro, NO tengo ninguna acción CellClick en el grid

Comment: El error te da con el datagridview vacío o ya tiene filas

Comment: cuando ya tiene filas y le hago clic a una celda, si hago clic en una parte vacía no me da ningún problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Después de andar preguntando, buscando un poco, gracias a @gbianchi y a [Esta respuesta del homólogo inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4494216/8166997) llegué a la conclusión del problema. citando/traduciendo al autor original de la respuesta:

> Supongo que ha vinculado una lista inicialmente vacía (u otro tipo de colección que no genere eventos de cambio de lista) a su
> DataGridView, y luego ha añadido elementos a esta lista.
>
> Los elementos que añada se mostrarán correctamente en su cuadrícula,
> pero al hacer clic en una fila se producirá esta excepción. Esto se
> debe a que el CurrencyManager subyacente informará de su posición
> actual en la fila como un desplazamiento de -1. Se mantendrá así
> porque la lista no informa de los cambios en la cuadrícula.
>
> Sólo debe vincular su lista a la rejilla si tiene algunos elementos en
> ella para empezar, o volver a vincularlos cuando los añada.

Entonces, tomando en cuenta lo anterior, lo único que cambié es convertir mi `List<T>` en un `BindingList<T>`, quedando las modificaciones de la siguiente manera:

```
private readonly BindingList<DgvDetalleNota> DetallesNotas;
        public FrmPuntoVenta()
        {
            DetallesNotas = new BindingList<DgvDetalleNota>();
            InitializeComponent();
            DetallesNotas.AllowNew = true;
            DetallesNotas.AllowEdit = true;
            DetallesNotas.AllowRemove = true;
            DetallesNotas.ListChanged += DetallesNotas_ListChanged;
            SetDgv();
        }
        private void DetallesNotas_ListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            SetDgv();
        }
```

Aprovecho el método de la bindingList llamado listChanged, que hace que, cada vez que se modifique algo en la lista, haga una acción, la cuál, en mi caso, es repintar el datagrid.