# Quiero implementar el sort al hacer click en la cabecera de un datagridview

Tags: c#, windows-forms, linq, datagridview

Quiero implementar el `sort` al hacer click en la cabecera de un `datagridview`:

```
var query =
    (from rol in db.Rol
        select new
        {
            RolID = rol.RolID,
            RolN = rol.RolN
        }).ToList();

dgv1.DataSource = query;

Esta parte no me funciona

if (this.Orden == "ASC")
    dgv1.Sort(dgv1.Columns[this.Columna], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
else
    dgv1.Sort(dgv1.Columns[this.Columna], ListSortDirection.Descending);
```

Mensaje de error : `"Para que se pueda ordenar, un control DataGridView debe estar enlazado a un objeto IBindingList."`

Antes de un datatable lo pasaba a `BindingSource` y funcionaba, pero ahora quiero cambiar a `LinQ`.

Comment: Alguna respuesta te sirvio?

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y pon ese codigo ahi, para q se te entienda bien

Comment: Coloque mejor la pregunta con mi código "Quiero implementar el sort al hacer click en la cabecera de un datagridview desde LinQ" ahi puedes ver mejor mi codigo pro favor.. gracias

Comment: el código es relativamente el mismo, no sé qué quieres ver...

Answer (score 1):

hace un tiempo tuve un [problema similar.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/447977/45793) En sí, el error está en que una lista no puede ser implementada al 100% de funcionalidad en un `datagridview` (para no explicar cosas más técnicas). Sin embargo, una lista enlazada, `BindingList` en inglés, sí puede. bastaría con que cambies la línea que te devuelve una lista en base tu `query` de `linq`, a que se guarde en una lista enlazada. sería algo así:

```
var query = new BindingList<MyObject>((from rol in db.Rol
        select new
        {
            RolID = rol.RolID,
            RolN = rol.RolN
        }).ToList());
```

Espero que mi respuesta te sirva, saludos! :D

Comment: Coloque mejor la pregunta con mi código "Quiero implementar el sort al hacer click en la cabecera de un datagridview desde LinQ" ahi puedes ver mejor mi codigo pro favor.. gracias